# Pokémon Go crashes when I try to login

Tags: pokemon-go

So I mistakenly uninstalled Pokémon Go and I reinstalled it and when I logged in using google, the game crashes. I am using an Samsung Galaxy S6. What am I doing wrong? It says: unfortunately Pokémon Go has stopped when I choose an account. I really want to get back to my account but it just won't work. I've tried re downloading the game but that does nothing. Help!

Comment: Could you run the game before you un-installed it?

Comment: @Fezodge III yes I could.

Comment: @DylanBlack did ya try reinstalling it or the OS?

Comment: In all seriousness; have you tried entirely restarting your phone? As in powering it down, rebooting it, and attempting to login again?

Comment: Does the app actually crash or do you just get a message that you cannot login? Have you tried logging in from a friends phone on PoGo? That should normally work, and maybe if you logout on that phone it might solve it? If not then perhaps your account was banned/ temporary blocked?

Comment: Can you post a crashlog?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the app data/caches? Is your device modded (rooted/whatever)?

Answer (score 3):

*Don't worry about your account; all your data is stored server side and will be restored. I personally swapped to a new phone and could keep playing from where I left off just fine.*

Firstly, make sure you've completely rebooted your phone to clear out any active apps and try launching Pokémon GO with no other apps running just to make sure this isn't an issue about having too little memory available.

If that doesn't work here's what you can do to completely reset every bit of data for Pokémon GO which should hopefully make it able to launch again (I doubt what you have is a hardware issue since the S6 is a very high-spec phone which shouldn't have any issues rendering the game).

The following instructions should work for any phone running Android 6 Marshmallow.

1. Open the settings app.
2. Tap the menu item called 'Apps' or 'Applications' (This name can differ between devices; ex. the Nexus 5X says 'Apps' and the Samsung Galaxy S6 says 'Applications').
3. *Specifically for the Samsung Galaxy S6*: Tap the item called 'Application Manager' to show your installed apps instead of the default Samsung ones.
4. Find the item named Pokémon GO in the list and tap it.
5. You should see the app name and icon at the top and a list below. Tap 'Force Stop' at the top.
6. Now tap storage from the list below.
7. You should see two buttons, 'Clear Data' and 'Clear Cache'. Tap 'Clear Data' ('Clear Data' should also clear the cache).
8. Tap back once to return to the menu where you can see the 'Uninstall' button and tap it.
9. Pokémon GO should be completely uninstalled with all of its data removed too. Go to the Google Play store and download it again.
10. Attempt to login using your preferred account, it should launch.

What this process is attempting to do is clear every single bit of data related to Pokémon GO from your phone since sometimes an app uninstall won't completely remove it.

*If this doesn't work, please comment.*

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you see where you get stuck on the instructions? Also, one of my family members has an S6 and I might be able to see if the interface is that different once they are back in a few hours... I didn't think Samsung would have altered this from the way default Android works.

Comment: This didn't work. I did exactly what you said but I still can't log in. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Okay; so it's not an issue with the app install. You haven't used any extensions/cheats for the app, have you? Not trying to judge, but it's relevant.

Comment: No. I have not used any cheats, hacks, etc. Unless PokeVision counts.

Comment: I don't think Pokevision got people banned. Is it possible for you to test it on another phone to determine if this is just your account having issues like @Mr. Meeseeks suggested?

Comment: no, I am the only one in my immediate family/friends with an S6. My dad has an S7 which is the closest to what I use.

Comment: Not on another S6, just any phone at all.

Comment: not at the current moment, but I can later. Thanks for all your help! I need to get back to my CP 750 Pigeotto. :P

Comment: Ah; I think I found where the instructions differ for the Samsung S6. I'll add them in case it helps anyone else in the future.

Comment: Still can't log in D:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44166/discussion-between-venoda-and-dylan-black).

Comment: @DylanBlack just try to log in to your account from just any other phone (from a friend/family). If that works than the issue should be with your phone. That will at least narrow down where to look to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Without a crashlog or backtrace it will be impossible to know what could be causing the crash.  Even with the logs it might be difficult for an end-user to identify the cause of the crash, as the log may need to be symbolicated, etc.

I would open a ticket with Niantic by [reporting an issue signing in](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=265607).  There is also a [report a bug](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222061187) form, but I feel that this is specifically a log in issue, so the first link would be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this is - Log out and again Log in to the game.

But since you're already logged in and the game simply crashes on starting, here's something you can try:

1. Uninstall the current Pokemon GO App from your phone.
2. Download the latest version from the Play Store and install it.
3. Run it. Log in using the Google Account.

I too once faced this problem and following the above steps solved it for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no log of any sort. I would suggest clearing cache of google play services. because *google play services is the app that deals with logging in* to a google+ account in the game.

If this does not open then try Venoda's solution if you haven't already tried. I think after clearing cache of both app will resolve this issue.